# How are coins distributed?

Tags: draw-something

In DrawSomething, when either you or your opponent guess a drawing correctly, you get shown a screen that says "Drawsome!" and then both of your avatars, along with the number of coins that drawing was worth.

Do I get coins both when an opponent correctly guesses my drawing, AND when I correctly guess an opponent's drawing? Or is it only one or the other?

Comment: OMG REPSTEALER! XD Yay for inside jokes!

Comment: @Tristan ಠ_ಠ ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just tried it now, with my opponent guessing my 3-coin word and me guessing his 2-coin word. After both were successfully guessed, I see that I only got 2 coins. Thus **you only get coins for successfully guessing your opponent's word**.

EDIT: [Here](https://getsatisfaction.com/drawsomething/topics/how_does_coin_distribution_work#reply_8125497), you can see that an employee answered a similar question incorrectly by saying that it is equally distributed. This is wrong because, along with my experiment above, then a "Coin Distribution" chart would not exist in the stats pane.

[image: Coin Distribution]

Comment: That is disappointing - why do they show you the coins for your opponent's guess if you don't get them? :(

Comment: @AshleyNunn: I too was under the same impression. They should probably make the animation something different: have the coins go "into" the avatar of the person who's getting the coins.

Comment: yeah, something to distinguish who is getting coins would be fantastic, because I totally assumed I was getting coins for both things.

Comment: I also noticed that in the main screen under an avatar, you can click the stats button and it shows the coin distribution.

Comment: So the coin distribution stat in each game really means that whoever has the lowest %age is just drawing harder words worth more coins

Comment: @Poizn1: and/or getting easy words from their opponent.