# Is there any penalty for a wrong guess?

Tags: draw-something

Sometimes I'm tempted to write rude words to my friends (not random people!) as a joke guess. Is there any penalty for incorrect guesses, such as losing coins? There's no visual indicator, but then again it seems like the Draw Something interface is [not always very clear](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56582/how-are-coins-distributed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there's no penalty. You can guess as many times as you want!

I routinely give funny answers like "wtf" when I can find them.